# Updating multi level Embedded document in Mongo using reactivemongotemplate

Tags: reactive-mongo-java

I have an embedded document. How can I update the multilevel document? At the time of insert, using Document to store the document. When updating the embedded document with `update.set()`, I can only do a string and not as an embedded document(storing it as null other than string).

The `obj.getEmbeddedDocument()` is returning me an object. I am able to use Gson library to update, but that is getting stored as String instead of embedded document.

Any suggestions?

```
[{"test1":[{"inside1":"value","inside2":"value"},
 {"inside11":"value","inside21":"value"}]},

 {"test2":[{"inside1":"value","inside2":"value"},
 {"inside11":"value","inside21":"value"}]}]
```